# Unable to update/upgrade: binfmt-support; 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Kubuntu Studio, 21.10, fresh install.

When trying to update or upgrade, the first thing apt tries to get is binfmt-support, but doing so returns these errors:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 binfmt-support amd64 2.2.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/binfmt-support/binfmt-support_2.2.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Universe is enabled in sources.list (if that's even relevant); I notice that the URL in the error message says "impish/universe" where a similar line in sources.list says "impish universe."

I don't know what i don't know, but I do know I'm stuck and I haven't found any information on this that addresses the issue.

- I can't download *anything*. Tried for gufw, for instance, and nothing in the list of packages that come up can be found.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit2gtk/gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0_2.34.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb , for example, is 404, but it's what's being looked for by apt.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid source. I'd remove it from your sources list.  Also, FYI, Ubuntu 21.10 is past EOL.

Comment: I don't think I've ever posted a question where someone didn't tell me the version I'm asking about is EOL - and it doesn't matter the version, supposedly current or otherwise! In any case, I'm trying to update to 22 and can't because of the above errors. I'm not specifying the source, that's just what's being called upon by apt. What should it be?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: The *impish* only files were and are being removed from archive.ubuntu.com which is **expected** given the release is EOL.  The *move* occurs after that as is documented.   **Your issue is related to EOL**

Comment: But preventing me from upgrading to the next LTS release. I was TRYING to move to a supported release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/)

Comment: fyi: Brian (*bdmurray*) has been recently doing a few fixes on this with *hirsute* & *impish*; at least the messages will be less confusing going forward at a minimum, but all issues can be avoided if you *release-upgrade* during the supported life of the product.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: I was able to update the relevant packages by,

1. backing up sources.list;
2. replacing sources.list with a version from a previous ubuntu release;
3. run apt update;
4. installing the packages I needed;
5. restoring the sources.list backup;
6. run apt update

Software Center shows the system is entirely up to date. Why ubuntu would need a package that isn't in its current repositories is beyond me. Maybe someone else has that answer.

Comment: *"Why ubuntu would need a package that isn't in its current repositories is beyond me"* - That's not what happened. When you add sources, you change the catalogue of packages available which can change dependencies. So when you restored default sources, the problem went away. Adding sources can sometimes be a messy way to install software because you're tinkering with the relationships between packages in your distribution. For example, PPAs are a type of source and they can mess up your system if they aren't compatible with your software. See: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)